# What could $id_{D(R)}$ and $id_{W(R)}$ mean in context of relation and reverse relation

Tags: notation, relations

Show that for a relation $R$ with a reverse relation $R^{-1}$ and $id_M:=\{(x,x)\in M\times M|x\in M\}$ following holds:

a) $id_{W(R)}\subset R\circ R^{-1}$

b) $id_{D(R)}\subset R\circ R^{-1}$

I don't know how those identities are defined and can't find them anywhere.

That makes it impossible for me to solve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$id_M$ is the *identity* relation on the set $M$.

It seems that $id_{D(R)}$ is the identity relation on the [domain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_of_a_function) of $R$.

If so, from the context we have to assume that $id_{W(R)}$ is the identity relation on the [codomain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Codomain).

Comment: hi, in german the codomain is called _W_ertevorrat, so $id_{W(R)}$=identity relation on the codomain of R?